# Testing AppleScript simulated user input in Travis CI

Tags: swift, applescript, travis-ci, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to test [this GitHub repository of mine](https://github.com/Samasaur1/Typer) using Travis CI. The problem I'm having is that what it does is use AppleScript's `keystroke` function to simulate user input. I can't figure out how to test this.

The repository is a Swift 4 library managed by the Swift Package Manager, in case that helps.

I've tried, on my computer, using a combination of `readLine()` and my typing method to get the output back as input, and I'm out of ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might look at [this post about unit-testing static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465267/is-it-possible-to-unit-test-a-static-library-project-using-xcodes-sentestingkit). In your tests, you could use `NEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown)` to detect keypresses (though there might be a better approach). Lastly, [`NSAppleScript`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsapplescript) will make your life a *lot* easier.